# how to update in-memory table dynamically using dolphindb database

Tags: sql, dolphindb, in-memory-tables

Is there any way to update an in-memory table dynamically using dolphindb? I need more suggestions to write a dynamic update function. Now I can only get the table name returned. I tried several methods to update the data for a specified table but failed.

Script 1:

```
table1=table(1..6 as id,2..7 as v, 3..8 as v1, 4..9 as v2, 5..10 as v3 );
share table1 as t1;
tableName ="t1";
update!(tableName, `v, 666);
```

Error report:

```
Read only object or object without ownership can't be applied to mutable function update!
```

Script 2:

```
updateSql = "update t1 set v = 999;";
parseExpr(updateSql).eval;
```

Error report:

```
Invalid expression: update t1 set v=999;
```

What's the correct syntax to update a specified table?

Answer (score 0):

Use DolphinDB's function [update!](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/u/update!.html) to update the columns in an existing table:

```
update!(table, colNames, newValues, [filter])
```

Here table is a DolphinDB table. The error occurs because your script defines the table type to be of STRING type. Use [objByName](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/o/objByName.html) to change it:

```
update!(objByName(tableName), `v, 666);
```

If you want to know more about dynamical expression generation, [meta programming](https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_EN/blob/master/meta_programming.md) will be of help.